# Is there any difference in setting element style to empty string vs setting to 'initial'?

Tags: javascript, css

I mean in a practical sense. I know that setting empty string on style property will clear the property inline styles and setting 'initial' will actually add this property with the 'initial' value but from the practical point of view that would be the same?

Comment: All in all setting a style property to an empty string might produce the same result as setting it to 'initial' **if the browser's default style is the same as the inherited or stylesheet value.** However, they function differently, as one removes the inline style, while the other explicitly sets it to the initial value.

Comment: It depends on the browser implementation, and how it handles an empty string. Most commonly, yes though, but not guaranteed at all.

Comment: Yes because empty string **removes** the style and setting it to initial **adds** an style in style attribute which has higher weight than potential css styles in your stylesheets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, using `""` removes the property from the element's style, making it unset. In contrast, `initial` sets the property to its initial value. In the MDN article on [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial), it warns about using `initial` on [inherited properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Inheritance#inherited_properties). That does appear to be a place where `""` vs. `"initial"` makes a difference (they suggest you might want `inherit`, `unset`, `revert`, or `revert-layer` instead). Here's their example from inherited properties, with code that sets the `color` on the `em` to `""`, `"initial"`, and `"unset"`:

```js
test("em-blank", "");
test("em-initial", "initial");
test("em-unset", "unset");

function test(id, value) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.color = value;
}
```

```css
p {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Using <code>""</code>:</p>
<p>This paragraph has <em id="em-blank">emphasized text</em> in it.</p>

<p>Using <code>"initial"</code>:</p>
<p>This paragraph has <em id="em-initial">emphasized text</em> in it.</p>

<p>Using <code>"unset"</code>:</p>
<p>This paragraph has <em id="em-unset">emphasized text</em> in it.</p>
```

As you can see, using `initial` the color of the `em` is the *initial* color the text would have (black) before the style turns the `p` and its contents green. In contrast, `""` and `"unset"` allow the green color to be inherited.

---

In comments on the question, [mandy8055](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77563859/is-there-any-difference-in-setting-element-style-to-empty-string-vs-setting-to/77563944#comment136740262_77563859) and [Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77563859/is-there-any-difference-in-setting-element-style-to-empty-string-vs-setting-to/77563944#comment136740266_77563859) suggest this may be browser-specific. FWIW, I tested the above on Chromium, Firefox, and Safari, so that's the three primary engines out there. I have no knowledge of the extent to which this is browser-specific. I've tried looking at the information for it referenced by the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#attr-style), which points [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-style-attr/#style-attribute) and [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/references.html#refsCSSATTR), but I don't see anything specifically addressing a blank string for a style value. Certainly a test shows the property being removed entirely:

```js
document.getElementById("target").style.color = "";
```

```html
<div id="target" style="color: blue">Right-click, inspect, and look at the style attribute; it's empty on Chromium and Firefox at least</div>
```